# Haskell - foldl' in terms of foldr and performance issues

Tags: performance, haskell, fold

While studying `fold` in depth with [A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/fold.pdf)
 I found an amazing definition of `foldl` using `foldr`:

```
-- I used one lambda function inside another only to improve reading
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl f z xs = foldr (\x g -> (\a -> g (f a x))) id xs z
```

After understanding what is going on, I thought I could even use `foldr` to define `foldl'`, which would be like this:

```
foldl' :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl' f z xs = foldr (\x g -> (\a -> let z' = a `f` x in z' `seq` g z')) id xs z
```

Which is parallel to this:

```
foldl' :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl' f z (x:xs) = let z' = z `f` x 
                    in seq z' $ foldl' f z' xs 
foldl' _ z _     = z
```

It seems that both of them are running in constant space (not creating thunks) in simple cases like this:

```
*Main> foldl' (+) 0 [1..1000000]
500000500000
```

**May I consider both definitions of `foldl'` equivalent in terms of performance?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In GHC 7.10+, `foldl` and `foldl'` are both defined in terms of `foldr`. The reason that they weren't before is that GHC didn't optimize the `foldr` definition well enough to participate in `foldr/build` fusion.  But GHC 7.10 introduced a new optimization specifically to allow `foldr/build` fusion to succeed while using `foldl'` or `foldl'` defined that way.

The big win here is that an expression like `foldl' (+) 0 [1..10]` can be optimized down to never allocating a `(:)` constructor at all.  And we all know that the absolute fastest garbage collection is when there's no garbage to collect.

See http://www.joachim-breitner.de/publications/CallArity-TFP.pdf for information on the new optimization in GHC 7.10, and why it was necessary.